# Recursive Fibonacci in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to figure out why this code isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    puts("what index of the Fibbonaci series do you want?");

    scanf("%d", &num);

    num = fib(num);

    printf("%d", num);

    return 0;
}

int fib(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (num == 1)
        return 1;
    else return (fib(num - 1)+fib(num-2));
}
```

---

P.S. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, and I was told that index's `0` and `1` are equal to `1`.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?  "It isn't working" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Please show an example of how it does not work for exable does fib(2) return the value 2, fib(3) return 3, and fib(4) return5?

Comment: @WeatherVane the recursion is supposed to actually return the values for 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., num and pass the final value back to the main so that in effect it has started from the bottom and counted num elements.

Comment: Note as an example, testing fib(4) by hand on paper following each recursion gives the correct value of 5. What is your problem?

Comment: To second @Draco18s comment, when I compile and run this code (under gcc) everything works fine (with a warning about using fib without a prototype).  What do you expect to happen that is not happening?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your function is not declared before `main()` and that is why your program does not run<sup>1</sup>.

Secondly, [Fibonacci Sequence is defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) either:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8,...
```

or

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8,...
```

where the recursive relation describing it is : Fib<sub>n</sub> = Fib<sub>n-1</sub> + Fib<sub>n-2</sub>

Which converted in C code would look like either something similar with what you got (first definition above), or a bit modified (using the second equally right definition):

```
int fib(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) {

        return 0;
    } else if (num == 1) {

        return 1;
    } else {

        return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
    }
}
```

### Note:

Both mine and your versions of the function are not very effective as they will make a lot of calls, most of them to calculate overlapping values, i.e. they will calculate a lot of [*overlapping subproblems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems). This could be fixed by using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Here is an example of an implementation, using the above notion of *memoization*:

```
// header needed for the container: map
#include <map> 

int mem_fact (int i, std::map<int, int>& m) {

    // if value with key == i does not exist in m: calculate it
    if (m.find(i) == m.end()) {

        // the recursive calls are made only if the value doesn't already exist
        m[i] = mem_fact (i - 1, m) + mem_fact (i - 2, m); 
    }

    // if value with key == i exists, return the corresponding value
    return m[i];
}

int fast_factorial (int i) {
    // key (Fibonacci index) - value (Fibbonaci number)
    std::map<int, int> memo;

    // initialize the first two Fibonacci numbers
    memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(0, 0));
    memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(1, 1));

    return mem_fact(i, memo);
}
```

then in `main`,if you call both like so:

```
int slow_fib = fib(10);

int fast_fib = fast_factorial(10);
```

you will get the same result: `slow_fib = fast_fib = 55`, however `fib()` will have to make **177** calls and `fast_factorial()` **only 19** calls.

---

<sup>1. `error: 'fib' was not declared in this scope`</sup>

Comment: But `0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8` does not satisfy the recursive relation. I believe, you forgot one `1` there.

Comment: Aside from formatting and removal of unneeded `()`, what is different between this `fib(int num)` and OP's?  I do not see any functional difference.

Comment: @chux One of the critetia is changed to show the equivalently right alternative definition and the OP gets some valuable information regarding the specific implementation he/she uses.

Answer (score 0):

`fib(0)` is `0`, not `1`. Whoever indicated/ordered that `fib(0)` is `1` is wrong.

Change

```
if (num == 0)
    return 1;
```

to

```
if (num == 0)
    return 0;
```

Comment: That would just pust the values returned by 1 so that it would be 0 1 1 2 3 instead of 1 1 2 3 ... The OP needs to specify which results he wants to see.

Comment: OP says *"i was ordered that index's 0,1=1"*

Comment: @WeatherVane That means that your change violates that order. the result of index 0 is supposed to be 1.

Comment: @sabbahillel starting at `0,1` or `1,1` is just a [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). I like the series `1,3,4,7,11,18,29,47,76,123,...`  because each term converges to phi power n.

Comment: @WeatherVane that was my point. The order that he specified just said that he wanted to start at the convention 1, 1, 2, 3, 5  but that does not say why his code is wrong. He should first say what he is seeing in his test that gives an invalid value.

Comment: @sabbahillel, I agree with you. The OP should indicate what he expects to see as output. Without that, any answer has the potential to be wrong.

Comment: "fib(0) is 0, not 1. Whoever indicated/ordered that fib(0) is 1 is wrong." -->  Was Fibonacci wrong? "Fibonacci began the sequence not with 0, 1, 1, 2, as modern mathematicians do but with 1,1, 2, etc." [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci#Fibonacci_sequence)

Comment: @chux, That's good to know. That does not indicate whether the first number in the original sequence corresponds to `0` or `1`. The first number in that sequence could correspond to `1`. No?

Comment: It is simply a convention today that `Fib[0]-->0` and `Fib[1]-->1`. It appears Fibonacci himself start the sequence with `1,1,2...`.  So is the first `Fib[0]` or `Fib[1]`? Suspect that was not as important as just stating the sequence.  The sequence can also run the [other way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Extension_to_negative_integers). What we call `Fib[0]` is a convention, not an absolute.  Something like [prime meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian#List_of_prime_meridians_on_Earth)

Answer (score -2):

Best thing is to avoid recursive form as possible.

```
int fib(int index) -- first fibonacci number is at index 0
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<index; ++i)
    {
        a = b;
        b += c;
        c = a;
    }
    return a; // <<-- value at index
}
```

Comment: The question is specifically about using the recursive method.